# Create a Data.Frame of the Vertices of an iGraph

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph, vertices, bipartite

I would like to create a data frame of the Vertices of a Bipartite Graph created using iGraph. When I try this, I get the following message:

```
x<- data.frame(V(graph))

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""igraph.vs"" to a data.frame
```

Is it possible to create a data.frame listing out all of the names of the vertices of a given graph? And if so, how?

Comment: could you add a minimal example by doing `dput(graph)` and copy/paste it in your question in order to be able to reproduce the example.

Answer (score 2):

Does the following work for you?

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_undirected_graph(c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
df <- data.frame(name = V(g)$name)
```